# Puzzle with some sort of math meaning to it?

Tags: soft-question, puzzle

This picture was posted in the math building at my college! So there has to be some sort of math puzzle/meaning behind it. Here is the picture of the puzzle and the instructions.
I have tried this several times and still cannot get it. 
[image: puzzle]
Here are the instructions
[image: instructions]

Let me know what you guys come up with! 
Thanks!

Comment: For a systematic approac, you might convert this to a "simpler" puzzle with twice as many nodes (say $X$ is replaced with $X_r$ and $X_y$) and an arrow $X_r\to Y_y$ if there is a red arrow $X\to Y$ and an arrow $X_y\to Y_r$ if there is a yellow arrow $X\to Y$.

Comment: I vaguely remember seeing something like this graph, but it was for testing divisibility by (some certain number). Does anyone now what I'm referencing/forgetting?

Comment: I think this puzzle is impossible...if you trace back from the goal then you find you must get to $L$ in order to solve. However tracing back further you find that to get to $L$ you must have got to $L$ earlier.

Comment: @fretty:  but on the return to $L$ you are on the other color arrow, so it is not obvious it is a problem.

Comment: Good point, I have found the optimal solution then, it is ABCDEFKTV(Z1)(Z2)VTKFEDIJRSZYXWOLGBAGLOWXYZ(Z1)(Z2)

Comment: Found this by tracing backwards and noticing that only one route doesn't land you in a loop...or in an uneccessary repetition of letter/colour pair

Comment: @fretty do you know what the author means when he says... "Can you find the least amount of edges needed to solve the maze?"

Comment: Isn't it obvious? He means to find the shortest route through the maze...

Comment: By brute force computation, I have confirmed @fretty's answer: $\text{start} \to A \to B \to C \to D \to E \to F \to K \to T \to
V \to \text{star} \to \text{frown} \to V \to T \to K \to F \to
E \to D \to I \to J \to R \to S \to Z \to Y \to X \to W \to O \to
L \to G \to B \to A \to G \to L \to O \to W \to X \to Y \to Z \to
\text{frown} \to \text{star} \to \text{goal}
$.

Comment: @fretty He calls them edges, so that was kind of confusing. He could have simply said, "Find the shortest route".

Comment: Well I have no bearing on that, I don't know the guy that made the puzzle...

Comment: It would be a long wait until August, 2330 to get the answer.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:  no math magic, just informed trial and error.  These are often easier if you work backwards from the goal.  You have only one path for the first eight steps backward, then a guess.  One of the options brings you back to where you were, but having arrived from the other color.  That should give you confidence that it is the correct path, as constructors of puzzles like things like that.  I find a solution that has $40$ steps.

In reverse, I get $\def\ot{\gets}\text{GOAL}\ot * \ot \otimes\ot Z\ot Y\ot X\ot W\ot O\ot L\ \\
\ot G \ot A \ot B \ot G \ot L \ot O \ot W \ot X \ot Y\\ 
\ot Z \ot S \ot R \ot J \ot I \ot D \ot E \ot F \ot K \\
\ot T \ot V \ot \otimes \ot * \ot V \ot T \ot K \ot F \\\ot E \ot D \ot C \ot B \ot A \ot START$

I suspect this is the intended solution because of the two big loops retracing steps.

Comment: How can you go from C->D->I

Comment: @fretty:  good point.  Working on it.

Comment: @RossMillikan did you come up with anything?

Comment: @Christopher23:  Yes I have updated it.  My solution agrees with fretty's.

Comment: No force (brute or other) is needed to see this is the shortest solution. Up to the first $L$ there is no choice. Then the option $L\gets M\gets P\gets O\gets L$ is useless (parity preserved), so the journey continues as indicated to the first $K$. There continuing to $J$ would again make a parity-preserving loop, so the sequel up to $D$ is necessary. From there the $4$ step endgame is clearly optimal. Other slutions (visiting $N,Q,H$) do exist.